Why is rotational kinetic energy not explicitly considered in the energy analysis of a simple pendulum?
In analyzing a simple pendulum, conservation of mechanical energy typically involves gravitational potential energy and translational kinetic energy. However, I noticed that rotational kinetic energy is not explicitly included in such analyses.
Does the translational kinetic energy already account for this rotational motion, or is it omitted because of simplifications such as assuming the bob is a point mass? How would the analysis change if the pendulum had a large, extended bob with a significant moment of inertia?

Doesn't the KE calculated from the bob's speed fully account for its KE?

A balance wheel is like a pendulum with an extended bob, but it's not powered by gravity. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Balance_wheel

The simple pendulum is idealized. The bob is treated as a point mass. Furthermore, the amplitude is kept small enough that $sin(\theta) \approx \theta$. The mass of the rod is ignored. Friction is ignored.
If you had a larger bob, gravitational potential energy and translational + rotational kinetic energy would convert back and forth. It works out that rotational energy is proportional to translational energy in this case. So it would make little difference. For a given amplitude the pendulum swings a little slower and has a little longer period than the simple calculation. This is similar to a disk rolling down an inclined plane slower than sliding down the same plane without friction.
Since the pendulum never rotates very fast, the difference is small. Ignoring it makes the analysis simpler, allowing you to focus on the physics principles instead of the calculation. The error is no worse than ignoring the other approximations.
